# null value is evaluating to TRUE

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have empty value (null) for "homeTeamScore" field on Parse backend. Parse field type is Number.

However, condition below is evaluating to TRUE. And then breaking inside the execution block when it is TRUE.

```
if (team.objectForKey("homeTeamScore") != nil) {
// execute some code
var homeTeamScoreInt: Int = team.objectForKey("homeTeamScore") as Int! // <- this is where code throws exception
}
```

I cannot figure out what's going on. Why null value is evaluating to TRUE?

Code below:

```
println("homeTeamScore") 
println(sweet.objectForKey("homeTeamScore"))
```

prints:

```
homeTeamScore
<null>
```

Comment: `if let homeTeamScoreInt = team.objectForKey("homeTeamScore")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`team.objectForKey("homeTeamScore")` is `NSNull` in this case use:

```
if (team.objectForKey("homeTeamScore") != nil && team.objectForKey("homeTeamScore") is NSNull == false) {
    // execute some code
    var homeTeamScoreInt: Int = team.objectForKey("homeTeamScore") as Int! // <- this is where code throws exception
}
```

This example shows difference between how `nil` and `NSNull` are printed:

```
print(NSNull()) // "<null>"
var a: Int?
print(a)        // "nil"
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you. I knew I should have understood the difference between nil and NSNull.